# How to add parse.com library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, parse-platform

I am new in codeigniter . i can easily work with parse.com library on core php like this

```
<?php
// define location of Parse PHP SDK, e.g. location in "Parse" folder
// Defaults to ./Parse/ folder. Add trailing slash
define( 'PARSE_SDK_DIR', '../src/Parse/' );
// include Parse SDK autoloader
require_once( 'autoload.php' );
// Add the "use" declarations where you'll be using the classes
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
// Init parse: app_id, rest_key, master_key
ParseClient::initialize('id', 'id2', 'id3');
// save something to class TestObject
$testObject = ParseObject::create("TestObject");
$testObject->set("foo", "bar");
$testObject->save();
// get the object ID
echo $testObject->getObjectId();
echo '<h1>Users</h1>';
// get the first 10 users from built-in User class
$query = new ParseQuery("_User");
$query->limit(10);
$results = $query->find();
foreach ( $results as $result ) {
// echo user Usernames
echo $result->get('username') . '<br/>';
}
```

but i am unable to use this in codeigniter . please help me how i can add parse.com in codeigniter and use this.
please provide me some direction and example

Comment: You have to create a library with referrence to this API.

Comment: This may help you. https://github.com/st028/codeigniter-parse.com-library

Comment: i does not find correct solution

Comment: Where you stuck? in library? or what?

Answer (score 0):

download CI library from here 
[parse.com](https://github.com/st028/codeigniter-parse.com-library) paste all code inside your application/libraries folder. make sure you have created custom config parse.php file sample

```
    <?php

/**
 * Parse keys
 */

$config['parse_appid'] = '';
$config['parse_masterkey'] = '';
$config['parse_restkey'] = '';
$config['parse_parseurl'] = 'https://api.parse.com/1/';

?>
```

and in your sample controller ParseSample.php try this.

```
    <?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class ParseSample extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $temp = $this->load->library('parse');
        $testObj = $this->parse->ParseObject('testObj');
        $testObj->data = array("testcol" => "it works");
        $return = $testObj->save($testObj->data);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($return);
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($return);
        exit;
    }

}
```

Hope someone might feel helpful.